# I already have my drive partitioned. How do I install Windows 7 on it?

Tags: mac, boot-camp

For some reason Boot Camp it seems that boot camp is not letting me install Windows on the partition I already have. When it shows my available drives, it shows my drive and says it's my startup disk with a windows partition. Thing is that I am not allowed to select it as an install destination! It's empty now. This partition exists from before and used to have windows. I since got rid of windows but I need it again. I don't want to re-format my whole disk just to re-partition it again which is what it seems it wants me to do. I'm stuck here any help would be appreciated.

Thanks much!

Comment: I hope this is not too vague. I can't seem to find anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the correct extension in the win partition? it should be NTFS

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, but I don't recommend you install Windows 7 on pre-existing partitions. Its okay to have pre-existing partitions in the disk, but not to install Windows 7 on them.

What you have to do is just delete the partition you was wishing to install Windows 7 to and tell the Windows installer you want to install it on the **unpartitioned space**. It will then create its partitions there automatically.

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty straightforward. How do I delete the partition? So, when I do delete it, it won't really go away correct? Otherwise i  would have to reformat my disk which I'm not prepared to do.. And it will automatically make the partition to where it was? Sorry, just a tiny bit confusing.

Comment: The Windows installer itself can do that, just check the options under the partitions list.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you not recommend installing Windows 7 on pre-existing partitions? Own experience, or some other source?

Comment: @TFM - Its complete non-sense that you shouldn't install Windows 7 on existing partitions.  Windows installer will format a partition if it needs to be formatted.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound completely, this recommendation makes no sense. I always install Windows on pre-partitioned disks when I don't want the System Reserved partition to be created.

Comment: Because a default Windows 7 installation will use at last 2 partitions, one hidden partition with 100MB used for protected system stuff and the actual partition with the remaining space. You cannot create this disposition manually, neither it will allow you to install Windows 7 over an preexisting setup like this. It can only be created by telling the Windows installer you want to install it to the unpartitioned space on the disk.

Comment: The 100MB System Reserved partition is not required for proper functioning of Win7, and you can do without it unless you use BitLocker or don't have access to the DVD and require WinRE.

Comment: For well for some reason I was only able to get the Win7 disk to boot by deleting the pre-existing partition and then doing the partition again with boot camp. Win7 setup finally loaded but I was never able to get it to install to the partition I had just made, even after formatting it in windows' setup screen. I just don't understand what could be going wrong. Perhaps I got a bunk version of windows.. ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if it happens with every version but it is pretty restricted when it comes to the format and flags of the partition, thats why you should just tell it to install to the unpartitioned space and let the installer do its thing. Its easier and more guaranteed this way.

Comment: @Ramhound and Karan: Yes, I wanted to point out same thing. I don't really like it when people answer stuff like they are the ones writing the code. "More guaranteed this way"? By whom, Microsoft?

Comment: If you know so much about Windows partitioning perhaps you should answer the guy. I'm might be no expert, but at last I'm throwing some useful personal experience here. My solution is simple, safe and functional, and answers perfectly to his needs without any complicated schemes or installing third party programs.